# ListView performance in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an Andorid appliation which will list a lot of books by a `ListView`, in fact I've used `ListView` for a while, I  know the basic usage of it.

And I also read this paper: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

However I found that even I follow the tips mentioned in the article for example use the "View recycling" and "Async loading", scrolling the ListView looks no-smooth.

This the adapter:

```
class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {
    private List<Book> data;

    public BookAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Book> data) {
        super(context, resource, data);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new DynamicBookView(getContext());

        }

        Book bk = getItem(position);
        DynamicBookView bookView = ((DynamicBookView) convertView); //so said view recycling
        bookView.setBook(bk);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Book getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public void swap(List<Book> books) {
        data.clear();
        data.addAll(books);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
public class DynamicBookView extends RelativeLayout {
    private ImageView bImage;
    private TextView bName;
    private TextView bAuthor;
    private TextView bDesc;


    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestHandle lastRequset;

    public DynamicBookView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DynamicBookView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.common_dynamic_book, null);
        addView(v, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        bImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_image);
        bName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_name);
        bAuthor = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        bDesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_description);
    }

    public void setBook(final Book book) {
        DynamicBookView.this.reset();
        bName.setText(book.name);
        bAuthor.setText(book.author);
        bDesc.setText(book.description);
        if (book.icon != null)
            fetchImageForBook(book);
        if (!book.loaded) {
            // loadBook is an async operation which use `AsyncHttpClient` too
            BookServer.getInstance().loadBook(book, new BookServer.BookServerLoadListener() {
                @Override
                protected void onComplete() {
                    setBook(book);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void fetchImageForBook(Book book) {
        //get from local:


        if (lastRequset != null) {
            lastRequset.cancel(true);
        }
        lastRequset = asyncHttpClient.get(book.icon, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                bImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(responseBody, 0, responseBody.length));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

    }


    public void reset() {
        if (lastRequset != null) {
            lastRequset.cancel(true);
        }
        bName.setText("");
        bAuthor.setText("");
        bDesc.setText("");
        bImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
}
```

So I wonder if there is anything I can do to make the scroll more smooth?

**Update:1**

Once I remove the loading codes:

```
public void setBook(final Book book) {
    DynamicBookView.this.reset();
    bName.setText(book.name);
    bAuthor.setText(book.author);
    bDesc.setText(book.description);
}
```

Then the performance is acceptable.

And BTW, a request would take 2-3 seconds for get response.

**Update:2**

I am not sure if you notice that, each view for the list item will trigger two Async task:

```
public void setBook(final Book book) {
    bName.setText(book.name);
    bAuthor.setText(book.author);
    bDesc.setText(book.description);
    if (book.icon != null)
        fetchImageForBook(book);
    if (!book.loaded) {
        // loadBook is an async operation which use `AsyncHttpClient` too
        BookServer.getInstance().loadBook(book, new BookServer.BookServerLoadListener() {
            @Override
            protected void onComplete() {
                setBook(book);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Generally, a `Book` just contain the `name` and `id`, then I have to retrieve the detail of the book like `author` `description` and `image` field. Then I will trigger another task to fetch the image. Now I have comment the line `fetchImageForBook(book);` that's to say I just display the book without load the image, but the scrolling is still no-smooth.(I can not get the information once a time, since we do not serve the service)

Comment: If the http operation is replaced with a local one, will the performance improve?

Comment: I have not add the local support yet, since the data would be changed frequently, so online is necessary.

Comment: Ok so if the http element was removed would performance improve? Your structure is getting the elements from the web on request from the view, so I would have thought that is were the performance issues are being created?

Comment: Yes,once I remove the asyn loading task(comment the `loadBook` method), then the performance is acceptable.

Comment: @hguser I don't know why you have to create a subclass of RelativeLayout and add view by your self, why don't make common_dynamic_book.xml as item view of your adapter and you can use ViewHolder pattern. Check this tutorial: http://jmsliu.com/1431/download-images-by-asynctask-in-listview-android-example.html

Comment: In fact, I have read the tutorial. Why I create a custom view to display the book is that there are almost 3 activities which will display books in the list, I do not want to make 3 copies for the same codes. And I think there is no difference between the `ViewHolder` pattern and mine, the key is the `view recyling` which means reuse the view, dot not create a new one when required.

Comment: First, the `ViewHolder` pattern has more performance optimization than `view recyling` only, you can look at Google I/O keynotes http://youtu.be/N6YdwzAvwOA Second, what 's stopping you from reuse adapter code?

Comment: Sounds right, I can use the `ViewHolder` pattern, but can you tell more about the `more performance optimization`? Since both the `ViewHolder` and my `DynamicBookView` use  the Async task, the only  difference is that the tutorial you mentioned use the built in `AsyncTask` while I use the `AsyncHttpClient`.

Comment: @hguser it isn't AsyncTask's problem, please check my answer

Comment: 1: `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(responseBody, 0, responseBody.length)`:  this function in your UI thread is really awful --> you should use some caching method.
2: recursive in your `setBook` is not good idea too. Beacause, everytime you scroll (make change) your listview, a lot of `setBook` is called. --> avoid it (loading before setting to adapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ViewHolder pattern` for more performance optimization because it can be cached and avoid to call `findViewById()` many times.

> scrolling the ListView looks no-smooth

Keep in mind that if you just don't do heavy tasks while rendering view, your list view should be smoothed.
From your code, I can see your problem is that you create bitmaps from byte array many times and don't cache them.

```
 bImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(responseBody, 0, responseBody.length));
 bImage.setImageBitmap(null);
```

If you just get images from remote server, I recommend you use some image loader libraries like UIL, picasso, Volley... because they can cache bitmap into disk or memory to improve performance, or you can do it by yourself (download in background, cache and load into view)

Here is an example from my adapter that using android [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader):

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_document, null);      
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

   ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(item.getImagePath()),viewHolder.imageView);
 }
```

It's very simple and I even don't see any performance issue while scrolling listview.
**Update**:
From your [BookServer](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7853380/) source code, I think your problem is here:

```
    @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            //do the hard job here   // what is this ???
            listener.onComplete();
        }
```

I don't know what hard job you did in this method, but the problem is this callback method run on **UI thread**. It causes performance issue while the asynctask doesn't because  it run on background thread.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure if it is the image loading that cause the problem, can you check my `update 2`?

Comment: @hguser First, as I said, you should user viewhoder pattern (you still can reuse it). Second, can you please comment `DynamicBookView.this.reset();` too? You don't need to reset all views before updating them (especially for image bitmap). Finally, I doubt that your image loading tasks don't cause scroll lag, as you don't reuse any bitmaps while scrolling. If you still getting this problem, the last one I can guess is your load book method.

Comment: Ok,I will comment the `DynamicBookView.this.reset();`, why I use this line is that I  am afraid that the reused view may display an old book while the current book is being loaded. And I agree with you that the image loading task donot cause the scroll lag, I will change to `viewholder` pattern and try again.

Comment: Hi, R4j, I tried to change to the `viewholder` pattern, and I got a significant performance improvement. But I am not exactly sure why? Since both use the `async` loading. And even I change the code like this:http://paste.ubuntu.com/7852812/, once I use the `BookServer.getInstance().loadBook` instead of the `new DownloadAsyncTask().execute(viewHolder);` I will still get the scroll lag.

Comment: So you mean you got a performance issue in `loadbook` and not in  `asynctask`?

Comment: Sounds like that, but I can not understand why. The only difference I can saw is that I made the `viewholder` filed `final` when I use the `loadbook`.

Comment: The whole codes of `BookServer` is long, I just paste the `loadBook` method:http://paste.ubuntu.com/7853380/

Comment: I think your problem is that you did some hard jobs on onSuccess callback method, and this run on UI thread, please check my updated answer

Comment: yup, as I said, if you don't do heavy tasks on UI task (especially while scrolling listview), your problem should be solved.

Comment: Sounds like you are right, I make the `parse` process in another asyctask, and the scroll is smoother...  Thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: Sounds like you are right, I make the `parse` process in another asyctask, and the scroll is smoother...  Thanks for your patience. :)